# How to loop a conditional dictionary in ansible

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements, jinja2

How can I use the loop in conditional dictionary?

I can only get the values that I need when using jinja2 sample:

```sh
- name: Debug
  debug:
    var: ansible_facts.services['{{item}}.service'].state is defined
  loop: "{{ my_items }}
```

This works fine and I can see the item.

I want to combine a conditional statement with a list and I can not figure out the syntax. Sample of code:

```sh
- name: Debug Conditional
  debug:
    var: ansible_facts.services['{{item}}.service'].status == "enabled"
  when: ansible_facts.services['{{item}}.service'].state is defined
  loop: "{{ my_items }}"
```

**Update:** Adding the ansible module that I am using [service_facts – Return service state information as fact data](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/service_facts_module.html)

Sample of working code if someone wants to replicate:

```sh
---
- name: Populate service facts
  service_facts:
  no_log: true

- name:
  debug:
    var: ansible_facts.services['{{item}}.service'].state is defined
  loop:
    - pcsd
    - nginx

- name: Debug Conditional
  debug:
    var: ansible_facts.services['item.service'].status == "enabled"
  when:
    - ansible_facts.services['item.service'].state is not defined
    - ansible_facts.services['item.service'].state == 'running'
  loop:
    - pcsd
    - nginx
```

The error after running the code:

```sh
PLAY [local] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [test : Populate service facts] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {"censored": "the output has been hidden due to the fact that 'no_log: true' was specified for this result", "changed": false}

TASK [test : debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=pcsd) => {
    "ansible_facts.services['pcsd.service'].state is defined": true,
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": "pcsd"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=nginx) => {
    "ansible_facts.services['nginx.service'].state is defined": true,
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": "nginx"
}

TASK [test : Debug Conditional] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'ansible_facts.services['item.service'].state == 'running'' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (ansible_facts.services['item.service'].state == 'running'): 'dict object' has no attribute 'item.service'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/tmp/ripl-env/roles/sample/tasks/test.yml': line 13, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Debug Conditional\n  ^ here\n"}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: can you give in input ansible_fact.services and my_items?

Comment: @CiroRa please see the update on my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your fixed playbook below with correct variable calls and correct usage of the debug module. If you read my comment again, you will see you did not apply my initial suggestion to access your service fact.

Note that I changed your last conditional to `or` since your will never have your `state` being undefined and equal to `running`

You probably want to have a look at the following docs:

- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html
- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/debug_module.html
- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html

```yaml
---
- name: Populate service facts
  service_facts:
  no_log: true

  vars:
   inspect_services:
    - pcsd
    - nginx

  tasks:
    - name: Debug the var itself
      debug:
        var: "ansible_facts.services['{{ item }}.service'].state"
      loop: "{{ inspect_services }}"

    - name: Debug a calculated value
      debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_facts.services[item + '.service'].state is defined }}" 
      loop: "{{ inspect_services }}"

    - name: Debug Conditional
      debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_facts.services[item + '.service'].status == 'enabled' }}"
      when: >-
        (ansible_facts.services[item + '.service'].state is not defined)
        or
        (ansible_facts.services[item + '.service'].state == 'running')
      loop:"{{ inspect_services }}"
```

Comment: You are right. `[item + '.service']` did the work. I was not aware that passing the variable before the single quote can be inserted into the key. Regarding the conditional. When you use condition in sequence just like `when: - foo - bar` then the condition is translated to `and` and not to `or` which is what I want. Thank you once again for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test exactly with your example, but you should use:

```
when: ansible_facts.services[item.service].state is defined
```

Comment: From OPs example, I suspect he should use `when: ansible_facts.services[item + '.service'].state is defined`. But it's hard to be sure without knowing the content of `my_items` and without a proof he as run `service_facts` beforehand. Moreover there are several wrong usage of `var` parameter in the `debug` module.

Comment: @Zeitounator Unfortunately it does not work. I have tried this as well. Please see the update on my question.